# Rails Action Text image attachement via api POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post, ruby-on-rails-6

attempting to POST to a rails API endpoint and looking to just post an image object to a ActionText field. this is what I've tried:

```
require 'rest_client'
require 'base64'
image_data = Base64.encode64(File.open("lastsnap.jpg", "rb").read)
  url = "http://localhost:3000/apiv1/sensors"
  data = { sensor: { image: { content_type: "image/jpeg", filename: "lastsnap.jpg", payload: image_data}}}
  header = {content_type: "json", accept: "json"}
  RestClient.post( url, data, header)
```

**calling this script and posting to the endpoint results in this error:**

```
Unpermitted parameter: :image
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/apiv1/sensors_controller.rb:27:in `create'
  Sensor Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "sensors" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2019-11-08 23:15:09.698765"], ["updated_at", "2019-11-08 23:15:09.698765"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/apiv1/sensors_controller.rb:27:in `create'
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/apiv1/sensors_controller.rb:27:in `create'
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms | Allocations: 2346)
```

so if we need to post in this format:

```
@message.image.attach(params[:images])
```

from our model

```
has_many_attached :images
```

and our controller

```
params.require(:message).permit(:title, :content, images: []
```

how should I be constructing the POST API call? it looks like the json I'm passing is not hitting the attribute on the object since its creating an object..

any assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are using `image` in your POST request and not `images` as one of the permitted params for the message. And in POST request you don't pass `image` as an array.